# Camera app not writing the image to file the second time

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I am trying to open a camera intent and load the captured image in Android. The issue is that the camera app writes to the input URI correctly and the written data can be successfully decoded into a Bitmap **only on the first call**. On subsequent calls, it does not write any bytes to the input file and I checked that the file located at that URI still has 0 bytes after control returns from the camera app.

Here is the code for creating the file URI for input to camera app.

```
private @NonNull Uri getImageUri() {
    Uri outputFileUri = null;

    final String imageFileName = "JPEG_"
        + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date()) + ".jpeg" ;

    File imagePath = new File(getFilesDir(), "images");

    if(!imagePath.isDirectory()) {
        imagePath.mkdirs();
    }

    File newFile = new File(imagePath, imageFileName);

    if (newFile.exists()) {
        newFile.delete();
    }
    try {
        if(!newFile.createNewFile())
            Log.e(MyActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "Error creating file");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(!(null != newFile && newFile.isFile())) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot create file ");
    }
    outputFileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
        this.getApplicationContext(), "com.myapp.android.fileprovider", newFile);


    if(null == outputFileUri){
        throw new IllegalStateException( "Cannot create file for clicking image");
    }

    Log.e(MyActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "output file uri " + outputFileUri);

    return outputFileUri;

}
```

Below is the code which opens the camera intent:

```
private List<Intent> getCameraIntents(@NonNull final Uri path){

    if(!mCameraIntents.isEmpty()) return mCameraIntents;

    @NonNull final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    @NonNull final List<ResolveInfo> listCam =
            getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);

    @NonNull final ArrayList<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<>(1);
    for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(res.activityInfo.packageName);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, path);
        cameraIntents.add(intent);
    }

    mCameraIntents.addAll(cameraIntents);
    return cameraIntents;
}

/**
 * Create a chooser intent to select the source to get image from.<br />
 * The source can be camera's (ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) or gallery's (ACTION_GET_CONTENT).<br />
 * All possible sources are added to the intent chooser.
 */
private Intent imageChooser() {

    // Determine Uri of camera image to save.
    @NonNull final Uri outputFileUri = getImageUri();

    @NonNull final List<Intent> allIntents = getCameraIntents(outputFileUri);
    allIntents.addAll(getGalleryIntents());

    @NonNull final Intent mainIntent = allIntents.remove(allIntents.size() - 1);


    // Create a chooser from the main intent
    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(
            mainIntent,
            getResources().getString(R.string.snap_app_chooser_message));

    // Add all other intents
    chooserIntent.putExtra(
            Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
            allIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[allIntents.size()]));

    mSnapUri = outputFileUri;
    return chooserIntent;
}
```

Then I simply call this,
`startActivityForResult(imageChooser(), REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);`

Below is the code for decoding the captured image written in the file URI by the camera app.

```
@NonNull @Override protected Bitmap doInBackground(@NonNull final Uri... snapUris) {

    Bitmap snap = null;
    try {
        Log.e(MyActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "snap uri " + snapUris[0]);

        snap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
               mActivity.get().getContentResolver(),
               snapUris[0]);
        if(null == snap ){
            InputStream is = 
                mActivity.get().getContentResolver()
                .openInputStream(snapUris[0]);
            snap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        }
        if (null == snap) {
            Log.e(MyActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "Problem with uri path");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        return snap;
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me in understanding why the camera app is not writing the captured image into the file URI after the first call? What changes between the first time the camera intent in invoked and the next time it is invoked that it cannot write into the second and the subsequent file URIs. Is the outputstream of the camera app not properly closing after the first call?

I tested it on Xiaomi and Lenovo phones and am getting the same behavior.

Comment: This sounds like an issue where the file is not closed. Make sure that the file is closed after you write to it

Comment: If you try to write to the file again, but it was not closed the first time, then such things can happen.

Comment: @bremen_matt No. Each time, I am generating a new file. As you can see in the getImageUri() method.

Comment: Are you getting anything in the logcat. Like perhaps `Problem with uri path`

Comment: Nothing. But let me check again.